# ng-hide is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-hide

I am new to angularjs.
When I click on "Click Me" the `toggle` method is called. The value of `test` changes from false to true, but `ng-hide` is not acknowledging the new value of `test`.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><span ng-hide="{{test}}">Testing</**strong text**td>
  <td><span>hello</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="cursor:pointer"><span ng-click="toggle()">Click Me</td>
  <td><span>hello</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var appX = angular.module('myApp', []);
appX.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.test = false;
   $scope.toggle = function(){
     $scope.test = true;
     console.log("toggle is working");
   };
});
```

Comment: You don't need to provide braces there Try like this `ng-hide="test"`

Comment: @Jigar7521 thanks. it is working.

Comment: Yes that is what i have provided answer below with more brief :)

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

test is not an expression, so remove the curly braces,

```
 <td><span ng-hide="test">Testing</**strong text**td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a syntax error. You are combining both expression binding and directive binding. Below code should work.

Replace `ng-hide="{{test}}` with `ng-hide-"test"`

Answer (score 0):

**The ngHide directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngHide attribute.**

Since it accepts expression so no need of curly braces!

Change:

```
ng-hide="{{test}}"
```

to

```
ng-hide="test"
```

You need to use curly braces if the directive was expecting `string` instead of `expression` as an attribute value.

Fore more info refer [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell that you are writing a angular code inside `ng-hide` as that is already angular directive, it will ditect `test` variable itself, so don't need to provide a braces over there to.

Simply try like : `ng-hide="test"`

Answer (score 0):

**Some code changes :**

- You forgot to close the `</span>`

  ```
  <span ng-hide="test">Testing</span>
  ```
- Remove `**strong text**` from the closing `</td>` element.

  ```
  <td><span ng-hide="test">Testing</span></td>
  ```
- Ass suggested by [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan), `test` is not an expression, so remove the curly braces.

  ```
  <td><span ng-hide="test">Testing</span></td>
  ```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = false;
   $scope.toggle = function(){
     $scope.test = true;
     console.log("toggle is working");
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
 <tr>
 <td><span ng-hide="test">Testing</span></td>
  <td><span>hello</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="cursor:pointer"><span ng-click="toggle()">Click Me</span></td>
  <td><span>hello</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```